# Unable to access WCF service hosted in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, iis-7

Hi there I have a simple 'proof of concept' WCF service built in vb.net and published via Visual Studio 2013 to the local IIS7 installation.  The service compiles and runs as expected in Visual Studio against IIS Express.  Unfortunately the service dos not appear to be accessible from the local browser when published and hosted in IIS7. The WCF service appears to be running, however when I attempt to access the sevice from the local browser I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is
temporarily unavailable.

Module IIS Web Core 
Notification MapRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070002 
Requested URL http://dino:80/DinoJsonWebService/getdata/400 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DinoJsonWebService\getdata\400 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous
```

The following browser entry works in IIS Express when run from VS:

```
http://localhost:15021/DinoJsonWebService.svc/getdata/400
```

When run against IIS7 I am accessing the local IIS session via an entry in the Windows Hosts file called 'Dino' on this basis I would expect the following entry to work:

```
http://dino/DinoJsonWebService/getdata/400
```

but no joy.  I also tried the following with the same negative result:

```
http://dino/DinoJsonWebService.svc/getdata/400
```

I've been banging my head against this issue now since last friday afternoon and its driving me insane!!! Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: what happens when you try to execute http://localhost/DinoJsonWebService.svc/getdata/400 ?

Comment: I get the following:


Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /DinoJsonWebService.svc/getdata/400

Comment: Ok, how about browsing the svc itself `http://localhost/DinoJsonWebService.svc`?

Comment: Same response Andrei.

Comment: Andrei, Eureka...!!!  I got it to work using the following URL:  http://dino/DinoJsonWebService/DinoJsonWebService.svc/GetData/400

In retrospect looking at the directory structure in IIS this seems to make sense, however just not what I was expecting.  Thanks for your assistance, sometimes it just needs a little collaboration to get the grey matter working :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the following URL: dino/DinoJsonWebService/DinoJsonWebService.svc/GetData/400